# Creating and using a temporary table to return a specific row, instead of running the query repeatedly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a program where a query is being run repeatedly to get a single row number (here called a "partition").

```
declare @partition int = {0}

;with candidates as
(
    select column1, column2,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by table1.column1) as RowNumber,
    ...
)
select c.column1, c.column2, 
from candidates c
where c.RowNumber - 1 = @partition
```

Instead of running this query every time I want to get a specific row, I'd like the query to write a temporary table and return the first row if the partition is zero, and return a row from the temporary table if the partition is not zero.

How would I go about doing that?  Can it be done in a single query?

Comment: I don't get why you need a distinct if it is a specific RowNumber?

Comment: @Blam: That's a good question, and it has caused some debate in our particular work circle.  I'll remove it here to avoid confusion.

Comment: @blam: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get not the stated question but why not

```
select column1, column2,
...
order by column1 
OFFSET @partition ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Is this a complex query that you want to cache?

OK cache

```
declare @partition int = {0}

IF @partition = 0
begin 
   truncate table TableCache;
   insert into TableCache (column1, column2, rownumber) 
   SELECT column1, column2, 
          Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY table1.column1, column2) AS rownumber 
   ......;
end
select column1, column2 
  from TableCache 
 where rownumber - 1 = @partition;
```

If this is program it would probably be way more efficient to the read column1, column2 into a List and refer to them from the program

Answer (score 1):

Why can you do this.

```
declare @partition int = {0}

IF @partition <> 0 
;WITH candidates AS 
( 
         SELECT   column1, 
                  column2, 
                  Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY table1.column1) AS rownumber 
         ......
 ) 
SELECT c.column1, 
       c.column2, 
FROM   candidates c 
WHERE  c.rownumber - 1 = @partition 
else
SELECT TOP 1 column1, 
         column2, 
FROM     table1 
ORDER BY table1.column1
```

Comment: OK, this looks good.  So I just need to put an INSERT INTO the temporary table on the ELSE side, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes, if you want to insert the result into temp table

Comment: The entire temporary table will be created on partition 0, and then referred to thereafter for partitions 1 through n.